# Is the cooldown on Throw Voice shout bugged?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Just unlocked it, if I use the max power shout it recharges instantly, if I use the weak one it takes ages!

Noticed in the shout screen the recharge times appear to be written in the wrong order, (30, 15, 5).

Is it likely that whoever created the shout entered the recharge times backward?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Throw Voice is unique in that there's no benefit to a higher magnitude power of the effect. The enemies are distracted, and investigating somewhere, or they simply aren't. It's a binary either/or scenario.

So, Bethesda had to find some other benefit to the 2nd and 3rd words - there was no magnitude or duration to increase like most other shouts. Their response? Lower the cooldown.

So while there's never any reason not to use the level 3 shout, it still requires 3 dragon souls to reach that point, and given that you learn all 3 words of the shout simultaneously (unique among non-unlocked shouts like Dragonrend or Clear Skies), it's not inconceivable that you may need to go dragon hunting before you can use the level 3 shout.

So to definitively answer your question: no. In all likelyhood, the recharge times *are* in the correct order, even though this is relatively unique among the shouts. (For another example, see Call of Valor, which has identical recharge times throughout all 3 levels).

Comment: They could have started out with a reduced effectiveness and increased the cool-down for more-effective voice throwing.